# Adding attribute value to each <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm having struggle accomplishing this :

I want jQuery to grab class name of each icon and write it in each p element

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-1"></i></div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-2"></i></div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-3"></i></div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

jQuery

```
function idk() {
    var icon_class = $(".icon i").attr("class"),
        icon_container = $(".col-md-4"),
        icon_p = $('.col-md-4 p');
        icon_p.each(function(){
            icon_p.text(icon_class);
        })
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    idk();
});
```

JsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/277gpp7r/2/

This code only duplicates the first icon class name and writes it in all "p" elements instead grabbing the each class name, but this is not what I'm trying to accomplish.

I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would loop through the `i`'s, store the class in a var, then find the `.col-md-4` ancestor and target the `p` in it and then add the class text to the `p`

```js
function idk() {
  $('.icon i').each(function() {
    var icon_class = $(this).attr("class"),
      $icon_p = $(this).closest('.col-md-4').find('p');
    $icon_p.text(icon_class);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  idk();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-1"></i></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-2"></i></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-3"></i></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This works perfect, but can you please explain why my actual code doesnt work and only duplicates first class, I would appreciate it!

Comment: @bertone_in yeah `var icon_class = $(".icon i").attr("class")` will grab the first class, then that's what you use as the text when you loop through your `p`'s. So you grab the first `i` class name, and put it in all of the `p`'s. You need to either loop through the `p`'s and find the `i` that's in the same parent, or do what I did and loop through the `i`'s and then add it to the `p` that is in the same parent.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function idk() {
  var icon_class = $(".icon i").map(function(){
  return $(this).attr("class")
  }).get().join( " " )
    icon_container = $(".col-md-4"),
    icon_p = $('.col-md-4 p');
  icon_p.each(function() {
    icon_p.text(icon_class);
  })
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  idk();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-1"></i></div>
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-2"></i></div>
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-3"></i></div>
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Map all the class into one array.
2. Then use that array as the text of each p

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this.

```js
function idk() {
        $('.col-md-4').each(function(){
        var icon_class = $(this).find(".icon i").attr("class");
        console.log(icon_class);
        icon_container = $(".col-md-4");
        icon_p = $(this).find('p');
             icon_p.text(icon_class);
        });
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    idk();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-1"></i></div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-2"></i></div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-3"></i></div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
function idk() {
  var icon_p = $('.col-md-4 p');
  icon_p.each(function(i, v) {
    find the i & its class in previous div and add it t the element
    var findClass = $(this).prev('div.icon').find('i').attr('class');
    $(this).attr('class', findClass);
  })
};
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/277gpp7r/4/)

Answer (score 1):

[`text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) is shortest way to do this:

```js
$('.col-md-4 p').text(function(){
   return $(this).prev().find('i').attr('class')
})
```

```css
p{border:1px solid #ccc; margin-top:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-1"></i></div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-2"></i></div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="icon"><i class="icon-class-3"></i></div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```